# how to make changes on an object and its child list property when passing them separately in method?

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, variable-assignment

I have a generic method, that takes object and a list, the list is a property of the object:

```
public void GetSingleLog<TJCls, TListObj>(int logId, out TJCls log, List<TListObj> lst)
{
  var json = (from j in context.TbHistoryLog where j.Id == logId select j.ObjectJson).First();
  var lists = context.TbHistoryLog_Lists.Where(x => x.LogId == logId).Select(x => x.ListJson);
  log = AuditHelper.DeserializeObject<TJCls>(json);
  foreach (var item in lists)
  {
    var listJson = AuditHelper.DeserializeObject<List<TListObj>>(item);
    lst.AddRange(listJson);
  }
}
```

I call it like so:

```
JClsTbInventory oLog = new JClsTbInventory();
oHistory.GetSingleLog(logId, out oLog, oLog.LstDetails);
```

the problem is that the log object is set, but the list is not. it's returned empty, even it has data inside the `GetSingleLog`.

Comment: Where are you initializing oLog.LstDetails?

Comment: in the constructor of the `JClsTbInventory`

Comment: Are you injecting it or directly initializing in the constructor? Can you please add initialization part as well in code?

Comment: You are resetting the `log` reference so the `lst` reference is no longer that intance's property.

Comment: in the default constructor:
`LstDetails = new List<ClsVwInventoryDetails>();`

Comment: You are clearly adding objects to `oLog.ListDetails`. `oLog` is then overwritten inside your method. I do not understand what you want to achieve. It will be more clear and simple to just return a `TJCls` object from your method, and remove both `out TJCls log, List<TListObj> lst` (which are useless).

Comment: Also, why is that method generic in the first place?

Comment: I created this method, because I have many classes that has lists property.. 
I save the object in a table and its list in another table as JSON objects. that complicated scenario drove me to this design, I'm aware of the other straightforward alternatives, but there are constraints!

Comment: Allow me to say that this design is flawed and really complicated. You should either create a common interface which every class with a list should implement (something like `IListContainer`) **or** more simply just serialize and deserialize the entire content of the object (including its list) to json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The dirty workaround approach

This is dirty and inefficient (because it will use expressions and reflection, which are slow), but it will allow you to use your (bad) model without changes:

```
public void GetSingleLog<TJCls, TListObj>(int logId, out TJCls log, Expression<Func<TJCls, List<TListObj>>> listSetter)
{
    var json = (from j in context.TbHistoryLog where j.Id == logId select j.ObjectJson).First();
    var lists = context.TbHistoryLog_Lists.Where(x => x.LogId == logId).Select(x => x.ListJson);

    log = AuditHelper.DeserializeObject<TListContainer>(json);

    var list = lists.SelectMany(j => AuditHelper.DeserializeObject<List<TListObj>>(j)).ToList();

    var property = (listSetter.Body as MemberExpression)?.Member as PropertyInfo;
    if (property == null) throw new Exception("Expression is not a reference to a property");
    property.SetValue(log, list, null);
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
JClsTbInventory oLog;
oHistory.GetSingleLog(logId, out oLog, o => o.LstDetails);
```

### The inheritance based approach

This approach is more reasonable and will use inheritance for achieving the same result, while keeping your model consistent.

You need an interface like this:

```
public interface IListContainer<TItem>
{
    void SetList(List<TItem> list);
}
```

And any class you want to retrieve using your method must implement it:

```
public class JClsTbInventory : IListContainer<MyClass>
{
    // ... other properties

    public List<MyClass> LstDetails { get; set; }

    public void SetList(List<MyClass> list)
    { 
        LstDetails = list;
    }
```

So you may use a simpler approach for retrieving your list:

```
public TListContainer GetSingleLog<TListContainer, TItem>(int id)
    where TListContainer : IListContainer<TItem>
{
    var json = (from j in context.TbHistoryLog where j.Id == logId select j.ObjectJson).First();
    var lists = context.TbHistoryLog_Lists.Where(x => x.LogId == logId).Select(x => x.ListJson);

    var log = AuditHelper.DeserializeObject<TListContainer>(json);

    var list = lists.SelectMany(j => AuditHelper.DeserializeObject<List<TItem>>(j)).ToList();

    log.SetList(list);

    return log;
}
```

Using it this way:

```
var oLog = oHistory.GetSingleLog<JClsTbInventory, MyClass>(logId);
```

Comment: is `SelectMany` here the equivalent to the `foreach` loop I used?

Comment: Yes it is. It will select each item from each list so you have a single IEnumerable of items